# Need help making h1 appear over-top of image

Tags: html

I've got a few lines of type set in a stylized h1 (type is skewed, underlined with border, etc). I'd like the h1 to appear over the top of the "bg-image" div class, but I'm having trouble. I'm new to using DIV structure.

```css
.bg-image h1 {
 display:inline-block;
  font-size:48px;
  font-family: "sofia-pro",sans-serif;
  font-weight:900;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:7px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
         -o-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
            transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
      text-transform: uppercase;
}
.bg-image {
    position: relative;
}
.bg-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
 background-size:cover;
    max-width: 2000px; /* corresponds to max height of 450px */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
            <div class="bg-image">
                <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/h12ymqn9v/Web_Hdr_Bground_1.jpg">
               <h1>Nobody</h1>
<br>
<h1>Ever Says</h1>
<br>
<h1>Seize</h1>
<br>
<h1 class="skewed">Tomorrow.</h1>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with position: relative and the distance in pixels you feel like for h1 to achieve your desired result. I just tried adding position: relative; and top: -450px;

```css
.bg-image h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:48px;
  font-family: "sofia-pro",sans-serif;
  font-weight:900;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:7px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
         -o-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
            transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
      text-transform: uppercase;
   position: relative;
   top: -450px;
}
.bg-image {
    position: relative;
}
.bg-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
 background-size:cover;
    max-width: 2000px; /* corresponds to max height of 450px */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
            <div class="bg-image">
                <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/h12ymqn9v/Web_Hdr_Bground_1.jpg">
               <h1>Nobody</h1>
<br>
<h1>Ever Says</h1>
<br>
<h1>Seize</h1>
<br>
<h1 class="skewed">Tomorrow.</h1>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use background-image on .bg-image class so you have more control.
Like this:

```css
.bg-image h1 {
 display:inline-block;
  font-size:48px;
  font-family: "sofia-pro",sans-serif;
  font-weight:900;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:7px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
         -o-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
            transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
      text-transform: uppercase;
}
.bg-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('http://s27.postimg.org/h12ymqn9v/Web_Hdr_Bground_1.jpg') center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
            <div class="bg-image">
               <h1>Nobody</h1>
<br>
<h1>Ever Says</h1>
<br>
<h1>Seize</h1>
<br>
<h1 class="skewed">Tomorrow.</h1>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to code and just saw this question. Have you tried the z-index? The z-index controls the z axis (up and down) of the webpage. Try putting z-index: -1 on css to make sure the picture will appear under the text on the webpage. Hope this helped!